# Apache/PHP - HTML output abruptly stops

Tags: php, apache, http, webserver

I have a PHP script that generates an HTML webpage and is served to clients via Apache. Most of the time the script works correctly, and the entire webpage is sent. However, sometimes the HTML output is truncated, stopping at some seemingly random, but consistent point in the document.

I have checked the Apache error logs, but there are no entries pertaining to the problem. I also restarted the server to see if I was encountering unknown memory problems, but the issue has persisted.

Any idea as to what could be causing the output truncation?

#### Server Configuration

Apache is configured to run PHP as FastCGI and other PHP scripts run correctly and output completely. PHP and Apache logging is enabled with PHP set to `E_ALL` and Apache set to `warn`.

Comment: Post the code..

Comment: @KarloKokkak The script is proprietary and under a license that prohibits disclosure. However, that is irrelevant to the problem discussed. I spent multiple hours searching for a solution online and was unable to find any information documenting this problem. I debugged my code and discovered that I had been setting a `Content-Length` header to the wrong value. I decided to post this Q&A (as permitted by SO policy) because I thought other people who run into similar problems in the future may benefit from my effort and documentation.

Comment: Also, if anyone is wondering why I answered my own question, plase see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/answer-your-own-question-qa-style) and the [Stack Overflow FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) for details on Stack Overflow's Q&A style posts.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible issues that could be causing PHP content to abruptly end. However, most usually result in an error being added to the server log. A couple common problems are:

1. The PHP process has run out of memory.
2. The PHP maximum execution time has been exceeded and the script was terminated.

Since no errors are generated in your situation and you have error reporting/logging enabled, it's likely that a faulty `Content-Length` header is set somewhere in the script. If the `Content-Length` header is less than the actual content length, the content is truncated and then sent to the browser.

To correct the problem, try the following:

1. Check your PHP script for calls to `header('Content-Length: '...)`
   and verify all length calculations are being performed correctly.
2. Remove calls to `header('Content-Length: '...)` if they aren't necessary.

Normally when left unset, the `Content-Length` header is automatically calculated and set to the correct length.

As a last resort, you could also unset the `Content-Length` header later in the script (before content output begins) with `header_remove('Content-Length')` if you are unable to determine the source of the incorrect header. However, please note that this is **not** recommended since it simply works around the underlying issue instead of identifying and correcting it.

Comment: plus one for out of memory.